# Map single key to compile and open LaTeX PDF

Tags: vimrc, filetype-tex

I use VIM for writing in LaTeX and I would like to have a single key to compile the text and open a PDF of it.  I have the line

```
map <F10> :!pdflatex % && start %.pdf
```

in my vimrc.  It seems to compile fine, but `%` represents the filename including the file extension, so the second command will not run (it is attempting to start `filename.tex.pdf`).  Is there a way to call the filename without the file extension?  For example, `%` returns `filename.tex`.  Is there something that would return just `filename`?

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You could try using a filename-modifier like `:r` or a combination of several like `:t:r`. `:t` should allow you to get the tail of the path, that is just the last element in the path (`baz` in `/foo/bar/baz`). And `:r` the root of the path, the path without the extension of the last item (`/foo/bar/baz` in `/foo/bar/baz.c`). So you could try: `!pdflatex % && start %:r.pdf` or `!pdflatex % && start %:t:r.pdf`

Comment: @saginaw You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @electriccello You might be interested in my LaTeX plugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex). It provides a mapping (default `\ll`) that starts [latexmk](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/latexmk/) in continuous compilation mode, which IMHO is a very convenient way of working with LaTeX documents.

Comment: I think the linked answer is better, but a quick modification to your current code is `start $(basename % .tex).pdf`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a filename-modifier like `:r` or a combination of several like `:t:r`.

`:t` should allow you to get the tail of the path, that is just the last element in the path (`baz` in `/foo/bar/baz`). And `:r` the root of the path, the path without the extension of the last item (`/foo/bar/baz` in `/foo/bar/baz.c`). So you could try one of the 2 following commands:

```
map <F10> :!pdflatex % && start %:r.pdf<CR> 
map <F10> :!pdflatex % && start %:t:r.pdf<CR>
```

If your filenames may contain special characters which you want to protect from the shell, you can use the function `shellescape()`. But in this case you would also probably have to:

- use the function `expand()` to force the expansion of `%` and `%:r`
  before the call to `shellescape()`,
- build the mapping with a concatenation of strings to force the evaluation of the functions before sending the command to the shell,
- execute the result with the command `:execute`.

Maybe something like this:

```
map <F10> :execute '!pdflatex ' . shellescape(expand('%')) . ' && start ' . shellescape(expand('%:r') . '.pdf')<CR>
```

And if your filenames may contain special characters which you want to protect from Vim (like `!`, `%` and `#`, because they have a special meaning on Vim's command-line), you can pass a 2nd non-zero argument to the `shellescape()` function.

```
map <F10> :execute '!pdflatex ' . shellescape(expand('%'), 1) . ' && start ' . shellescape(expand('%:r') . '.pdf', 1)<CR>
```

For more information, see:

```
:help filename-modifiers
:help :execute
:help expand()
:help shellescape()
```